# Button action not working when button frame is changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod

Am trying to change the button frame according to the orientation change but button action is not detecting if frame is changed.

"`addButtonsOnScrollView`" methode is called from "`viewWillAppear`" method

Here is my code

```
//scaleFactor = 320 if portrait orientation scaleFactor= 480 if landscape orientation

- (void) addButtonsOnScrollView 
{ 
   containerViewForButtons = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scaleFactor-100, 22, 100, 37)];
      addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addFriend:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [addButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  addButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 37);   
  [containerViewForButtons addSubview:addButton];
    [self.view addSubview:containerViewForButtons];
}

- (void) addFriend:(UIButton *) button {
   NSLog("Button clicked....");
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
   if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

       [self layoutLandscapeView];
      }
      else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

       [self layoutPortraitView];
      }
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
- (void) layoutLandscapeView {

     containerViewForButtons.frame = CGRectMake(380, 22, 100, 37);

}
- (void) layoutPortraitView {

    containerViewForButtons.frame = CGRectMake(220, 22, 100, 37);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding the button to a scrollview (looks like it from the method name)? Most likely your scrollview's content size is not getting updated when you rotate. That is why the button is not able to detect touch.

Answer (score 1):

Initially create `UIButtonTypeRoundRect` instead of `UIButtonTypeCustom`. So that you can see the visibility of the Button. Check button is visible and touchable.

Another thing may be Change `UIControlEventTouchDown` to `UIControlEventToucUpInSide` That will help I guess.

Comment: I applied the changes suggested by you, but it didn't work for me.Button is visible but not touchable.

Comment: Are you sure you are able to touch your button ? Code is okay. There is no any other reason that event should not fire. Only thing is you need to check whether button is touchable. Check scrollview interaction and button interaction property.

Comment: button is not touchable .I set button properties userInteractionEnabled = YES & enabled = YES ,but doesn't work

Comment: thanks for your support.The problem was the scrollview's content size was not getting updated when you rotate.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `containerViewForButtons.clipsToBounds = YES;` just to check if the button is still in the views frame and not being cut off. If `clipsToBounds` is set to NO you'll still see the button but it wont intercept any touches, because it is out of the `containerViewForButtons` bounds

Answer (score 1):

Try this......

```
- (void) layoutLandscapeView 
{

   [containerViewForButtons removeFromSuperview];
   containerViewForButtons.frame = CGRectMake(380, 22, 100, 37);
   [self.view addSubview:containerViewForButtons];
}
- (void) layoutPortraitView 
{

   [containerViewForButtons removeFromSuperview];
   containerViewForButtons.frame = CGRectMake(220, 22, 100, 37);
   [self.view addSubview:containerViewForButtons];
}
```

Comment: removing and adding view on rotation may cause "wait_fences" warning and delays rotation.